# growth stages of Maize

Tags: agriculture

I am reading about growth stages in Maize and found this image.

[image]

I downloaded a brochure of a maize variety grown in Brazil.

[image]

On the right column, it says male flowering 63 days after planting (947 degree days) and female flowering 63.5 days after planting (955 degree days).

When stage does the male and female flowering happens in the first image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first image, flowering occurs in the stage labeled "Pollination", which is when the male releases pollen and the female accepts pollen.  It give the time as 56-63 days after emergence, but note the asterisk ("*"); the footnote for it says their given times vary by "growth class" (such as "early" or "late"), indicating that these numbers are just a guide and actual times will vary by the cultivar (breeding strain) selected.